# React-native aplication database reads optimization

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react-native application with React-Native and Firebase firestore. I've got a feed where posts are shown, and a screen for each post with more details. The problem is, on the feed posts are shown, and when you go to each post screen, everytime the specific post is read. If you go back and then come again to the post screen, it's read again.

I thought a way of optimizing the database reads for this is to simply create a Redux action to fetch all posts and keep them in store. But I am faced with a challenge.

When I normally fetch them without Redux, I am using props to do it. When you go to a specific post screen, I fetch the post data where props.route.params.postId == firebase id. I couldn't find a way to replicate this with Redux.

Anyone has any idea over how this could be done?

EDIT:

In feed page, I'm fetching all posts

```
firebase.firestore()
                .collection('allPosts')
                .get()
                .then((snapshot) => {
                    let postsData = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                        const data = doc.data();
                        const id = doc.id;
                        return { id, ...data }
                    })
                    setAllPosts(postsData)
                })
```

Then I map through each, display some info about them and let the user navigate with props to a different screen with more info about post.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Post', { postId: item.id)}>
                  <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                        
                  <Image
                      style={styles.media}
                      source={{ uri: item.media }}
                   />
   </TouchableOpacity>
```

And in Post Screen I have the following fetch

```
firebase.firestore()
            .collection("allPosts")
            .where(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), '==', props.route.params.postId)
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                let post = snapshot.docs.map(doc => {
                    const data = doc.data();
                    const id = doc.id;
                    return { id,...data }
                })
                setPost(post)
                
     })
```

As I said above, I couldn't find a way to make Redux work for this(keep all posts data in store and let me access it for each specific post)

Comment: This can be explained better with screenshots. And maybe a dump of your code.

Comment: @XChikuX added edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also just store the `posts` directly to local storage:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("allPosts")
  .get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    let postsData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
      const data = doc.data();
      const id = doc.id;
      return { id, ...data };
    });
    setAllPosts(postsData);
    localStorage.setItem("allPosts", Json.stringify(postsData));
  });
```

And later read it directly from there with:

```
const allPosts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allPosts"));
```

If you can't find the data in `allPosts` make a call to get it from database. That is very easy to build in directly than to play with `redux` to do it so. Especialy the part with loading from database when there is nothing in the store. With `redux` you would eventualy have empty state before you get realy one so you would load the data even if you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This sounds like a good idea! However I cannot get it to make it work on my app because of how the app is built. I have a feed, with all posts(gets them from db), and then you can click on each specific post, and you can view more data about the post.  I do this with props in react navigation, and i use the .where in firestore function to search for firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId() == props.route.params.docId(id of doc in firestore).

Comment: I was thinking that there may be a possibility to make this work without reading again on each post page. Example, read all posts data once on feed, and keep it there, and display from that. Is that doable with localStorage?

Comment: Yea I get it. And that is exactly what I want to explain. You can search trough all downloaded posts from the local storage. Just don't use a `where` loop trough all `local` posts and find the one you need.